# Computationally inexpensive pseudorandom 2d number

Tags: parametric, random

I am trying to calculate a random position on a grid in a very inexpensive manner for a gpu kernel however I can not quite figure out how to get it right.

You see the function that generates the random coordinate can have only one input "t". t is an **integer** and it has a range of 0-250. This restraint bars me from using the usual gpu function I have heard of.

What I have been playing with is a parametric function i remember from algebra where `x=sin(ax)` and `y=cos(by)` as you change the values of `a` and `b` this equation generates an intresting shape. It would seem as you increase the least common multiple of a and b that the shape becomes more complex.

[image]

I figure if I can get this function to be "complex" enough any random t on the function should generate a "random" point.

My problem is I don't have enough knowlege of this function to customize it for my scenario. To make this function seem random the function needs to be complex. I have found values of a and b such as 55.7 and 33.9 that do generate a sorta complex function (not quite complex enough and I cant figure out how to determine an ideal complexity with these values) however when I apply them they tend to have a bias of some sort. In this case the x axis was just about perfectly distributed however the y axis ended up being grouped into obvious bars.

I believe this is because t is an integer.

How can I avoid x and y axis groupings with my values of a and b?

It is also possible that I am going about this entirely the wrong way and I should pick a different function.

Comment: Trading quality for "computationally inexpensive" is potentially dangerous, but it depends on how much "random" you need, and how much "pseudo" you can tolerate. Many cheap generators have pretty obvious flaws (2d points concentrated on just a few straight lines, e.g.), but whether that may cause much harm depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at first, happy New Year! I must admit that this one has got me down writing a little bit, but is seems a very interesting problem. As I see it - correct me if you had something else in mind - a notion of "complexity" for your problem would be as follows:

> Find $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}_+^2$ such that the self-intersecting points of the curve $c(t)=(\sin(at),\cos(bt))$ are "almost" uniformly distributed in a rectangle $[-\delta,\delta]\times[-\delta,\delta]\subseteq[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$, $\delta>0$.

I chose only the self-intersecting points of $c$ just for reasons of simplicity; when they seem to be uniformly distributed, the plane is almost "gridified" - seems to be a grid - by the plot of $c$. For instance, for $a=97$ and $b=98$ the plot of $c$ is:

[image]

Now, at first we sould be able to, at least describe, the self-intersecting points of $c$. So let
$$I_c=\{c(t)|\exists\ s\in\mathbb{R}\text{ with }c(t)=c(s),\ t\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

So, the points in $I_c$ should be exactly the solutions of the following system of equations:
$$c(t)=c(s),\ t\neq s\tag{1}$$
Let us play around with $(1)$ a little bit:
$$\begin{align*}
c(t)=c(s)&\Leftrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\sin(at)=\sin(as)\\
\text{and}\\
\cos(bt)=\cos(bs)
\end{array}\right\}\\
&\Leftrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{c}
at=2k\pi+as\text{ or }at=2k\pi+\pi-as\\
\text{and}\\
bt=2k\pi+bs\text{ or }bt=2k\pi-bs\\
\end{array}\right\}\\
&\Leftrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{c}
t=2k\frac{\pi}{a}+s\text{ or }t=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{a}-s\\
\text{and}\\
t=2k\frac{\pi}{b}+s\text{ or }t=2k\frac{\pi}{b}-s\\
\end{array}\right\}\\
\end{align*}$$

From this, four "sub-systems" occur:
$$\begin{align*}
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
t=2k\frac{\pi}{a}+s\\
\text{and}\\
t=2k\frac{\pi}{b}+s\\
\end{array}\right\}\tag{1.1}\\
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
t=2k\frac{\pi}{a}+s\\
\text{and}\\
t=2k\frac{\pi}{b}-s\\
\end{array}\right\}\tag{1.2}\\
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
t=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{a}-s\\
\text{and}\\
t=2k\frac{\pi}{b}+s\\
\end{array}\right\}\tag{1.3}\\
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
t=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{a}-s\\
\text{and}\\
t=2k\frac{\pi}{b}-s\tag{1.4}\\
\end{array}\right\}\\
\end{align*}$$

System $(1.1)$ implies that $a=b$ which is a dump case, since, then, $c$ is a circle. Also, system $(1.4)$ implies that $(2k+1)b=2ka$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, which is a very specific case - b should be odd and many more restrictions - that will not bother us much - this will be clear in the following lines. So, we are left with systems $(1.2)$ and $(1.3)$ that give the following solutions for $t$:
$$\begin{align*}
t&=k\pi\frac{a+b}{ab}\\
t&=k\pi\frac{a+b}{ab}+\frac{\pi}{2a}
\end{align*}$$
and for $s$:
$$\begin{align*}
s&=k\pi\frac{a-b}{ab}\\
t&=k\pi\frac{a-b}{ab}-\frac{\pi}{2a}
\end{align*}$$
where, in all the above, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ (well, we should exclude $k=0$ but, later on, we will not take into account these points).

Wait, what?! Aren't there infinitely many integers? So, are there infinitely many self-intersection points of $c$? Well, no, there are finitely many elements of $I_c$, and this can be proved as follows; let $d=\gcd(a,b)$ be the greatest common divisor of $a,b$. Then curve $c$ has a periodicity of $T=\frac{2\pi}{d}$. Indeed, let us calculate 
$$c\left(t+\frac{2\pi}{d}\right)=\left(\sin\left(at+2\pi\frac{a}{d}\right),\cos\left(bt+2\pi\frac{b}{d}\right)\right)=(\sin(at),\cos(bt))=c(t)$$
since $d|a$ and $d|b$. There is, also, no number $T'<T$ that has this property for $c$, due to the maximality of $d$ and the fact that $\sin$'s and $\cos$'s period is exactly $2\pi$.

So, we can restrict $c$ over the interval $\left[0,\frac{2\pi}{d}\right]$.

At this point, a note of yours made me have a deeper look into the way $e:=\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ estimates the number of elements of $I_c$. I will, intentionally let aside the majority of the calculations, since they are similar to the previous ones and I will just sketch the idea: Fix a point in $I_c$; so it must be of the form $(x,y)=c(t)=(\sin(at),\cos(bt))$. Now, cosnider a line parallel to the $x-$axis. Every intersection of $c$ with that line is of the form $(\sin(at),\cos(at'))$ for a 
proper $t'$. But, since that point is also a self-intersecting point of $c$, it should also be true that $c(t')\in I_c$ (this is where 
the calculations are ommitted). The same 
applies if we consider a line parallel to $y-$axis. So, at most all the pairs with numbers of the form described above, if we consider the 
sequence:
$$t_k=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{k}{2}\pi\frac{a+b}{ab} & \text{if }k\equiv0\mod 2\\
\frac{k-1}{2}\pi\frac{a+b}{ab}+\frac{\pi}{2a} & \text{if }k\equiv1\mod 2
\end{array}\right.$$
then, every combination of terms of this sequence gives a point in $I_c$. Now, consider also that $c$ is of periodicity $T=\frac{2\pi}{d}$. So, 
we must have that:
$$t_k\in\left[0,\frac{2\pi}{d}\right]$$
Approximately, this implies that:
$$k\leq\frac{4ab}{a+b}\frac{1}{d}$$
So, an oversetimation - a vast one, indeed - would be that there can exist, at most:
$$\left(\frac{4ab}{a+b}\frac{1}{d}\right)^2$$
points in $I_c$ - we may have a better estimation, but it is too tiring for our purposes. Now, to minimize this estimation, we should minimize 
the denominator and, especially, $d$ - since $ab$, eventually, "kills" $a+b$. So, the minimum value for $d$ is $1$ and, hence, we should 
choose numbers $a,b$ such that they are relatively prime. Note now, regarding $e$, that this is, as you noticed, directly connected with 
this estimation, since $ab=de$, so, minimizing $d$ maximises $e$.

Now, what about the distances of these points and their distribution on the plane? Well, as depicted in the following .gif (inform me if this does not open; it was quite large):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BWAvNGnkFqxpST8D5LB9GQmRkRwEw08G/view

where the green points are the ones generated by odd $t_k$'s and the purple are the even ones, $t_k$ gives us a nice way to find an estimation 
of the minimum distance between "consecutive" points in $I_c$. We will caclulate, at first $\lVert c(t_k)-c(t_{k+1})\rVert$. So, using known 
trigonometric formulas for the sum of sines and cosines, we have that:
$$c(t_k)-c(t_{k+1})=(2\sin\theta_a\cos\phi_{k,a},2\sin\theta_b\sin\phi_{k,b})$$
where 
$$\begin{align*}
\theta_a&=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{a+b}{b}\\
\theta_b&=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{a+b}{a}\\
\phi_{k,a}&=\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\frac{a+b}{a}\\
\phi_{k,b}&=\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi\frac{a+b}{b}\\
\end{align*}$$
So, 
$$\lVert c(t_{k})-c(t_{k+1})\rVert=\sqrt{4(\sin^2\theta_a\cos^2\phi_{k,a}+\sin^2\theta_b\cos^2\phi_{k,b})}$$
Note now that, for $b\sim a$ we have that:
$$\theta_a\sim\theta_b$$ and then:
$$\lVert c(t_{k})-c(t_{k+1})\rVert\sim2|\sin^2\theta_a|$$
which means that the points of $I_c$ are almost at stable distance, for a large area around $O(0,0)$ (that area can be found case-specifically, 
for given $a,b$; it takes some time to find a general formula).

So, for example, for $b=a+2$ or $b=a+1$ (you may accuse me of incosistency, since $(1.4)$ and its solutions have been excluded, but, as it has been 
mentioned, there is not much difference, at the estimation level) and for $d=1$ one can plot a nice grid in a large area of the $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ 
square.

So, to conclude, choose $a,b$ rather large, with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a\sim b$. Finally, here's a .gif

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c3erBWKkhkSfehCETHgnamUNTwtxl0kB

with $b=a+1$ and $a$ from $50$ to somewhere aorund $500$ - in the end, it really had some hard times...

Comment: Thankyou for all the expertise and time put into your incredibly useful solution!

Comment: You 're wellcome! :)